# Learning weights during training

Tags: neural-networks

Let's assume I have a net so the loss function is composed from 3 components: $C_1, C_2, C_3$, and each component is multiply by its weight $(w1, w2, w3)$. 
The weights should be a function of $\beta$, which is a function of the error/error rate/std etc, so the loss function can be written:

$$L=C_1 w_1(\beta) + C_2 w_2(\beta) + C_3 w_3(\beta)$$

In *Mathematica*, the loss would be:

```
  L = w1[beta]*C1 + w2[beta]*C2 + w3[beta]*C3
```

The net I have is shown in the diagram below.

The weights should be normalized I am guessing, and  sum to one.

I would like the network to be able to learn the optimal weights. How can I do it and which layers I need to add to my network? How can I use the error and calculate the error rate or the standard deviation of the error signal, **during the training process** ?

Edit:
The code that produced the above network is:

```
lossNet2 = NetGraph[
  <|"Net" -> UNET,
    "finalAddition" -> TotalLayer[],
   "C1" -> lossByWeights,
   "C2" -> lossByDev,
   "C3" -> lossByMinMax
   |>,
  {
   NetPort[ "Input"] -> "Net", "Net" -> NetPort["Output"],
   {"Net", NetPort[ "Target"]} -> "C1" -> "finalAddition",
   "Net" -> "C2" -> "finalAddition" -> NetPort["Loss"],
   {NetPort[ "Input"], NetPort["Target"]} -> "C3" -> "finalAddition"
   },
  "Input" -> {1, 1, 512}]
```

Any help will be appreciate.

Thanks,

Guy

[image]

Comment: When editing your question, I thought your objective function was the sum of the terms.  Is this correct?  Or do you have a multi-objective function (which would be a more complex problem.  Thanks

Comment: I think it would be helpful to include the code you used to produce the network.

Comment: I added the code, thanks

Comment: Getting this error message:  "NetGraph::netinvnodes: UNET is not a net function."  What is UNET?

Comment: UNET is a customized net that I built. The specific net is not relevant, It can be any net.

Comment: Well, could you post your code for UNET?